# spring security- how to decide landing url on controller code based on logged user

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am able to implement spring security but in spring security xml file, have to give target url. I need to decide landing page
on the server side controller code after successful login. Anybody plesae share though process here!

I have been followed example in below url:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

considering your mentioned example, 
inside spring-security.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true">
 <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
 <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
             authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        class="com.somepkg.security.MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

then inside MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler:

```
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    protected Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
 
    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
 
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        handle(request, response, authentication);
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }
 
    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);
 
        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            logger.debug("Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to " + targetUrl);
            return;
        }
 
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }
 
    
    protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
        boolean isUser = false;
        boolean isAdmin = false;
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
            if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ONE")) {// change roles accordingly
                isUser = true;
                break;
            } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_TWO")) {// change roles accordingly
                isAdmin = true;
                break;
            }
        }
 
        if (isUser) {
            return "/somepage.html";
        } else if (isAdmin) {
            return "/otherpage.html";
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
 
    protected void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            return;
        }
        session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
    }
 
    public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
        this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
    }
    protected RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
        return redirectStrategy;
    }
}
```